# how I can find with jQuery the next element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

how I can find the next class "comment" and shows it after I click "read" ?

```
<div class="preview">
<div class="messages">
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="circle left"><img src=""></div>
        <div class="name">Lars Mehrhoff</div>
        <div class="sep_20"></div>
        <a href="#" class="read"><i class="icon-comment"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="reply"><i class="icon-reply"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="read"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="trash"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
        <div class="comment">ASD</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="msg">
        <div class="circle left"><img src=""></div>
        <div class="name">Lars Mehrhoff</div>
        <div class="sep_20"></div>
        <a href="#" class="read"><i class="icon-comment"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="reply"><i class="icon-reply"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="read"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="trash"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
        <div class="comment">ASD</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery Code is this:

```
    $('.read').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.comment').show();
});

$('.comment').hide();
```

I would display only the comment that is next to the "read"

Comment: and if `siblings` is not enough for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30089307/274502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
$(this).siblings(".comment").show();
```

Comment: i doubt `.next()` will work with his structure though because it's not the next immediate sibling of `.read`

Comment: I think wirey is right in this case. `siblings()` will work but only because there is one node with a class `.comment` on the same level as the `.read` element clicked.

Comment: @antony .siblings() will work as the information provided by the OP states his HTML structure.

Comment: @wirey correct, I have removed the .next() example from my answer.

Comment: @97dave. Yes I said it will work, but only under that structure :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(this).siblings('.comment').show();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
$('.read').click(function(e) {

    $(this).parent().find('.comment').show(); 
});

$('.comment').hide();
```

I hope it can help